# I need to dispose all the declared objects from a class. but i do not know how many objects from that class

Tags: c#, object, dispose

I made array of objects with size x and Program used y number of objects from the class.I don't know the value of y.How can i delete all the objects.

Comment: Close the program

Comment: Some sample code may help to clarify what you trying to do... (Possibly you are re-implementing `List<T>` as homework assignment... but even that does not call for "how can I delete all the objects")

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a List instead of an array.

This way you can use the different methods available for deleting items from a list.
In this way, you could then use the [List.RemoveAll()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx) method to delete all items remaining in the list.

Comment: Question seem to be asking about disposing some, but not all objects... Using `List<T>` indeed sounds like a better idea than fixed size arrays, but it is somewhat unclear what OP is actually have trouble with.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov OP is asking "How can i delete all the objects".
The List.RemoveAll() will accomplish this.

Comment: "I need to dispose all the declared objects from a class" can be read in multiple ways... yours is one of them, just not the only one. Also `RemoveAll` does not really "delete" anything... Again your interpretation of the question may be correct - editing question may be good idea if you know exactly what OP mean when using words like "dispose" or "delete".